# How do I get more than one decimal spot?

Tags: java

I'm making a simple calculator (I'm a beginner), and I was wondering why when I divide 1 by 4, I get 0. I know it has something to do with the type of number. Here is my code:

```
private static void calc(int a, int b,String op){
    if (op.equals("add")){
        double ans = a+b;
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    if(op.equals("subtract")){
        double ans=a-b;
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    if(op.equals("multiply")){
        double ans=a*b;
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    if(op.equals("divide")){
        double ans=a/b;
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

I can't get my variable (ans) to have more than one decimal spot. And when the answer requires one (like 1/4), it just returns 0.

Help please.

Comment: Integer division. Cast one of the argument as double to avoid that (`double ans=(double)a/b;`)

Comment: Use either `double` or `float` or `BigDecimal` instead of `int` if you want your calculator to handle more than just whole numbers.

Comment: Have a look at the "Narrowing Primitive Conversion" section in Java language specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: Just to expand upon others comments, when you divide `int`s, java will take the floor of any float it gets, in your case you're getting a number < 1 meaning it will return 0. You can do two things here, change your parameters to `double` or cast each variable so `a/b` becomes `(double) a / (double) b`. You can look up anything further on how ints/doubles and casting works by a simple google search

Comment: @sreya - Not quite true.  Integer division rounds towards zero (that is, negative numbers go upwards).  The "floor" function always rounds downwards, so for negative numbers, it's not the same as integer division.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide on a double since all your result values in double.

```
private static void calc(int a, double b,String op){
}
```

Or simply :

```
if(op.equals("divide")){
    double ans=(double)a/b;
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to put the double there.  Try changing `double ans=a/b;` to `double ans= ((double)a)/b;

Answer (score 0):

Although the other comments and answers are correct, they do not give enough detail (IMO).

Although `ans` is a `double`, the value of the right side of the equation is still an `int`.

```
double ans = a / b;
// equiv to:
// double ans = (double)(a / b);
```

So when you evaluate this you get:

```
double ans = (double)(1/4);
           = (double)(0);
           = 0.0d;
```

To get around this, you will need to cast one or both of the operands to a `double`.

```
double ans = ( (double) a ) / ( (double) b );
           = ( (double) 1 ) / ( (double) 4 );
           = 1.0d / 4.0d;
          ~= 0.25d;
```

Also note with regards to @Salah's answer that the cast from integer to double has just been moved. Since you can implicitly convert an `int` to a `double`, calling the function with an integer (such as the literal `1`) will automatically convert the integer to a double. However, you may not want to allow non-integral numbers to be passed to your function, and if so, then this solution would not be correct.